# how to reject requests at server level and not pass them to the application?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal

Is it possible to put something to htaccess in the application directory, so that certain requests are rejected at server level and don't reach the application (Drupal in my case) at all, and don't spam the application log with "page not found"?

I thought that requests for files "forbidden" by htaccess are rejected by the server and not processed further, but they are not.

Example:

Suppose my own site domain is example.com. The htaccess has the following lines (this is a simplified setting to prevent hotlinking jpg images):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([-a-z0-9]+\.)?example\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule \.(jpg)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

It works, i.e. for example if I go to http://altlab.com/hotlinking.html and put an existing jpg address from my example.com site, it says that the image cannot be displayed. So it was blocked, ok. But the above request was also reflected in the Watchdog (Drupal's internal log), which is not ok.

Is there a method to reject requests from external domains for jpg files by the Apache server and not pass these requests further to the application?

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect with a 4XX status code.

```
RewriteRule ... [...,R=400]
```

Comment: I changed it to: RewriteRule \.(jpg)$ - [F,NC,R=400,L] but the requests are still visible in Drupal log. Also tried [F,NC,L,R=400].